# Getting started as a statistics consultant

Tags: careers

Just by being on CV for a little while now, I've noticed that a lot of the higher reputation users run their own consultation firms.  As a new(ish) statistician looking to start his own consultation business, what are some tips and/or advice you could give? More specifically:

- How did you get started consulting
- How do you find clients
- What is the frequency of jobs
- General $\frac{$}{hour}$ tips
- Any general advice for new consultants

In order to conform to the tag, please give advice which is irrespective of specialty or experience level.  Assume a knowledgable statistician who is looking to expand into private consulting.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was OT, as the `careers` tag description was a little vague.  If this question is too broad, I'll remove it and perhaps ask in chat.

Comment: This is a good general website for the topic http://community.amstat.org/cnsl/home . Their newsletters are very interesting for you, e.g., for question 4 they conducted an analysis in 2005 here http://www.amstat.org/sections/cnsl/newsletter/pdf_archive/vol23no1.pdf Consider joining the ASA section.

Comment: I've actually never seen this before, thank you @Momo. Definitely a lot of great material to explore.

Comment: I like the question--and obviously others do too--but it just doesn't fit our framework. Answers will unavoidably be individually subjective ("how did you get started"), localized in time and space (tips on billing rates), and unfocused ("any general advice"). There is a statistical consulting section of the ASA, which you should be able to find through @Momo's links, and they do exchange posts from time to time: that would be the ideal place to have this discussion for anyone in the US.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the explanation; I'll definitely check out the ASA.